# Create text file in asp.net using code

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I create a text file using ASP.Net? I tried using `Streamwriter` but it only writes to exist file:

```
using (StreamWriter _testData = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/data.txt"), false))
{                
    _testData.WriteLine(txtText.Text); // Write the file.
    _testData.WriteLine(txtLink.Text); // Write the file.               
}
```

So how do I create it. I have tried:

```
FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile(filename[,overwrite[,unicode]]);
```

but it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "it does not work"? Does it throw an exception? What is the exception then? Or your file is not created, and no exception is thrown?

Comment: where did you look for the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string FilePath = Server.MapPath("FILENAME.txt");
string FileContent = "Put File Content Here";
File.WriteAllText(FilePath, FileContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor creates the file for you if it doesn't exist, so you shouldn't have to change anything. Just be aware that specifying "false" in the constructor will overwrite the file each time this code is executed.

> Initializes a new instance of the StreamWriter class for the specified file by using the default encoding and buffer size. If the file exists, it can be either overwritten or appended to. If the file does not exist, this constructor creates a new file.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx